# Integration of complex exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Today, my professor presented the following integral
\begin{align*}
    \int_{}^{} e^{ix}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{e^{ix}}{i}
.\end{align*}
where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit. I was a bit confused about this result, since we haven't introduced differentiation nor integration of complex valued functions. So my question is: How is the integration of complex functions defined?

Comment: This is like a regular real integral, notice that the complex derivative of the exponential function is the same as the real derivative of the exponential function, and thus the same argument as in the real case holds.

Answer (score 2):

The other comments are not justified. But you can work this out with

$$\int e^{ix}dx=\int(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))dx=\int\cos(x)dx+i\int\sin(x)dx=\sin(x)-i\cos(x)+C=\dfrac{e^{ix}}i+C$$ where the integrals are real.

**Update**: an answer was modified and comments deleted since.

Answer (score 1):

Here the $x$ in $dx$ is a real variable so it is real integration, the confusion also arises because the bounds are not explicitly marked, so the fact it is a real interval is somehow hidden.

Would it be $dz$ then this would be a completely different animal and you'll have to integrate on a contour and this would be complex integration.

> It is not the nature of function that matters, but the nature of the variable.

So in this case the $i$ in the $e^{ix}$ just acts as a scalar, and it integrates as if it was $e^{\alpha x}$.

It we expand the integral we get:

$\begin{array}{lll}\displaystyle\int e^{ix}dx
&=\displaystyle\int(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))dx
&=\displaystyle\underbrace{\int\cos(x)dx}_\text{real integral}+\underbrace{i}_\text{scalar}\times\underbrace{\int\sin(x)dx}_\text{real integral}\\\\
&=\sin(x)+i(-\cos(x))
&=(i\sin(x)+\cos(x))\times\underbrace{(-i)}_{=\frac 1i}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{ix}}i\end{array}$